# Needed Help About Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have long struggled with programming languages ​​such as PHP, Javascript, HTML, etc. But my weakness is still very disturbing is about regex.

Previously I felt comfortable without understanding it but now I find the point where I have to use a regex function.

I want to replace a html tag that is created from a rich text editor, say [RTE] so that when I type `[code]` in the box and then I hit enter it will be translated by RTE `<div>[code]</div>`

What I need is to change the `<div>[code]</div>` into an opening html tag `<div class="code">`

I have tried using `str_replace()` PHP function as bellow :

```
$content = str_replace(
               '<div>[code]</div>',
               '<div class="code">',
               $_POST['content']
           );
```

but it's not work, I think maybe I need to use `preg_replace()` function but I can't.
Can someone help me what type the sample code to do that?

Comment: did you check whether $_post['content'] has values??

Comment: See here : http://www.regexr.com/ Community in side menu.

Comment: [Don't use regex with HTML!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: @Biffen soo what would I do?

Comment: @kefy Use a library of some kind, e.g. a DOM one.

Answer (score 0):

In `preg_replace()` function, you need to escape  `[`,`]` symbols, so that it would match the literal `[`,`]` symbols.

Regex:

```
<(div)>\[([^\]]*)\]<\/\1>
```

REplacement string:

```
<\1 class="\2">
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/9)